# How do you define "The beginning of the first [insert time unit]"?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I'm so confused. Say if it's "The beginning of the first day", how would you define this? If we're talking about linear functions, will it be defined as f(0) or f(1)? Because you could have graph this function separately. For example: http://puu.sh/ryDH7.png From this graph where you have hours as the time unit, "The beginning of the first day" would be defined as f(0). While for this graph http://puu.sh/ryDP1.png , it would be defined as f(1).

I need help defining this. Do I need more information to determine it?

I also need help on defining it in the sequence context, how do I determine which is the first term?

Comment: Monday will start at 00:00 and end at 24:00.

Comment: I would say that "the beginning of the first day" would be defined as $f(0)$ for both graphs. The label "1" on the "days" axis corresponds to 1 full day, i.e. you reach that point after the entire first day passes. (Think of it like we measure age - a child doesn't turn 1 until the very end of their first year of life. At the beginning of their first year of life they are 0 years old.)

Comment: I don't see the difference between your two graphs. Anyway,in a continuous representation of time, the first day is the **interval** between $0$ and $1$, the second day is the interval between $1$ and $2$, and so one...